# Pandas grouped data to Bokeh graph

Tags: python, visualization, pandas

I'm having trouble graphing Pandas grouped data in Bokeh.

```
company_id    company_score    date_submitted    company_region
AA            .07              1/1/2017          NW
AB            .08              1/2/2017          NE
CD            .0003            1/18/2017         NW
```

I've successfully grouped the data by `company_id`, and calculated the simple moving average of company_score using 10 days / inputs.

```
score_by_company = df['company_score'].groupby(df['company_id']).rolling(10).mean()

company_id    index           SMA     
BBG000B9WMF7  7613            NaN
              1911663         NaN
              1911664         NaN
              1911665         NaN
              1911666         NaN
              1911667         NaN
              1911668         NaN
              1911669         NaN
              1911670         NaN
              1911671    0.000002
              1911672    0.000002
              etc.       etc.
```

How can I translate this data into a time series graph, with each `company_id` being its own line?

I feel like I need to create a data dictionary off of the grouped data, but I'm not sure if that's the right approach.

Comment: You want to plot company score and time?

Comment: Correct, I'm having difficulty going from grouped data to a graph.

Comment: When you have grouped data, they are not at the same index level, so you need to loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the plots by looping over the groups from `groupby`...

Or this should also work..

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df['company_score'].groupby(df['company_id']).rolling(10).mean().unstack().plot()
```

See [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html) for more information on plotting with pandas dataframes and [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#iterating-through-groups) for looping over a groupby-object. Finally [this](http://blog.yhat.com/posts/aggregating-and-plotting-time-series-in-python.html) link is super helpful.