# Pandas df - FacetGrid - Need help with plotting

Tags: pandas, plotting, matplotlib, seaborn

Let's say I have a df with the below columns

```
Feed     ItemName
----     --------
FeedA      ItemA
FeedA      ItemB
FeedA      ItemC
FeedA      ItemA
FeedA      ItemB
FeedA      ItemA
FeedA      ItemC
FeedA      ItemC
FeedA      ItemC
FeedA      ItemA
FeedA      ItemB
FeedB      ItemC
FeedB      ItemB
FeedB      ItemB
FeedB      ItemB
FeedB      ItemC
FeedB      ItemA
FeedB      ItemA
    .....
    .....


    .....
```

I want to get the count of each `ItemName` grouped by `Feed` and build a Facet grid (for each `Feed`)

Whilst I tried 
`df.groupby(['Feed','ItemName'])['ItemName'].count()`
to the get the count split by `ItemName` & grouped by `Feed`, but am not sure on how plot that as graph.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas grouped data to Bokeh graph](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/29908/pandas-grouped-data-to-bokeh-graph)