# Pandas: Calculating the best seller to incorporate number of houses sold

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have been analysing seller data and trying to get insights. I have written a groupby statement to get the average price of selling for every seller

```
for seller,seller_df in g:

df=df.append({'Seller':seller,'AveragePrice':seller_df.Price.mean() }, ignore_index=True)
print(seller)
    df.sort_values(by='AveragePrice',ascending=False,inplace=True)
plt.figure(figsize=(15,30))
sns.barplot(data=df.dropna()[:100],y='Seller',x='AveragePrice')
```

The bar plot is only for the top 100 sellers and shows who has the max average selling price. [image: Plot]

I believe this method is inaccurate as I also should consider the amount of properties that he has sold in order to get the best seller. For e.g.: if A sold 20 houses with average 5 and B sold 200 with average 5, B should be the winner.So I have two questions:

1. How can I incorporate this in my code?
2. Can I optimise the code snippet?

I am a newbie and any help is appreciated. Please refer to this link for my Kaggle notebook. It does not contain the code posted here as I am doing the analysis locally but you can have a look at the data.

[Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/shinydhar/melbourne-housing-analysis)

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/29908/35644. This might help you to plot groupby pd, Also there is no link in your question, kindly edit it for the us to help you further.., it seems that you want to add the count also....

Comment: I have no issues in plotting. What I am trying to ask is that I would consider a seller better than the other even if the average price at which they sell their houses are same if, the latter sells more houses. I want to know how to calculate this average by incorporating that count into my code here. I do not know how to do it.

Comment: You define a new metric and use that instead of 'AveragePrice'

Comment: How do I do that in Pandas easily? I can use value_counts for the frequency of occurrence and use it. But I am unclear about the next steps.

Comment: Use counter from collections and the use map and create a new corresponding column..., Add a screenshot of your dataset

Comment: which is better, average of 4 with 1000 sales compared to 5 average of say 50 sales?

Comment: In this case we bring the count to a common denominator of 1000 and the latter is better. But is this a good approach. I need conceptual guidance here. Is my logic on the right track?

Comment: @Aditya: I do not understand this approach. Can you point me a GitHub/web/documentation link of what you are trying to provide as a solution? FYI-I am noob.

Comment: @KiriteeGak: Can we just use the total amount that every seller has sold?Is that a better approach?

Comment: In my opinion you can create a better variable like sellers credibility using number of sales and avg rating.

Comment: Exactly, do some feature engineering...

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the permissions yet to add a comment, because I'm new to the DS Stack Exchange, so I try it this way. @Shiny: what you write sounds a bit like you want to include confidence information into your plot. Have you thought about computing confidence intervals for the average prices you calculate? But anyways you still have the problem to define, how you incorporate the confidence in your output (e.g. do you want to order on the lower bounds of the confidence interval or rather on the upper bounds and what confidence level you want to apply. But maybe it's worth taking th

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of analysis, to calculate the total revenue of a seller as a feature seems sufficient, because it accounts for both amount of houses sold and house prices. Formula is the sum of all individual house prices sold.

```
df = seller_df.groupby(by='Seller')['Price'].sum().reset_index()
```

(Disclaimer: code untested)